# Dual Steenrod squares

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, duality, products, steenrod-algebra

Fix the ground ring $\mathbb{F}_2$ and let $X$ be a space with finite homology. Then we have an isomorphism $\Phi^i_X:H_i(X)\to H^i(X)^*,a\mapsto \langle-,a\rangle$ which allows us to define the dual Steenrod squares
$$\mathrm{Sq}_r:H_i(X)\stackrel{\Phi_X^i}{\to} H^i(X)^*\stackrel{(\mathrm{Sq}^r)^*}{\to} H^{i-r}(X)^*\stackrel{(\Phi^{i-r}_X)^{-1}}{\to} H_{i-r}(X).$$
I want to understand which formulae they satisfy. Many things seem easy: For example, the “dual” Cartan formula needs the comultiplication $\Delta:H_i(X)\to \bigoplus_{p+q=i}H_p(X)\otimes H_q(X)$ which is dual to the cup product, and one should get
$$\Delta_{i-r}\circ \mathrm{Sq}_r = \sum_{p+q=r}(\mathrm{Sq}_p\otimes\mathrm{Sq}_q)\circ \Delta_i.$$
What I am now trying to dualise is
$$\mathrm{Sq}^nx = x\smile x ~~~\text{ for }|x|=n.$$
The right hand side is obviously the cup product precomposed with the diagonal $\nabla:H^n(X)\to H^n(X)^{\otimes 2}\subseteq \bigoplus_{p+q=2n}H^p(X)\otimes H^q(X)$. We can find a map which is dual to this diagonal and of the form
$$D:\bigoplus_{p+q=2n}H_p(X)\otimes H_q(X)\to H_n(X),a\otimes b\mapsto a\,\# \,b.$$
We then should get for $a\in H_{2n}(X)$ the statement
$$\mathrm{Sq}_n(a) = (D\circ \Delta)(a).$$
However, this does not look very enlightening. Does this “wrongly graded product” $D$ have any meaning? At least, it satisfies the following property for all $\alpha\in H^n(X)$
$$\langle \alpha,a\,\#\,b\rangle = \langle\alpha^{\times 2},a\times b\rangle.$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the diagonal"?  $a\to a\otimes a$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is there any problem with this map?

Comment: It seams that the diagonal $\nabla$ imposes a coalgebra structure on $H^*(X)$ (which is not graded) and that $D$ is its dual a (non-graded) algebra structure on $H_*(X)$. Is there anything known about it?

Comment: Like, not being additive?